# Chemical potential in 1D

Tags: statistical-mechanics, solid-state-physics, electrons, chemical-potential

How is it possible to understand how the chemical potential $\mu$ of the electrons in the Sommerfeld theory of metals change, when the temperature $T$ is increased up to a small value above zero?

By computing the Sommerfeld expansion I know that, in 1D, $\mu$ increases as well as $T$, but I would like to know if it is a way to understand it quicker in a qualitative way.

On the contrary, in 3D $\mu$ decreases for increasing $T$. How is it explained?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One should think of $\mu$ as a parameter that solves the equation 
$$\begin{equation} n = \int f(E,\mu,T) g(E) dE \end{equation} $$ 
where $n$ is your particle density, $f(E,\mu,T)$ is your Fermi-Dirac/Bose-Einstein distribution function, and $g(E)$ is your density of states.

Now, one can easily see the dependence of $\mu$ on $T$ in each dimension due to the differences in $g(E)$ in each dimension. Since we have a quadratic dispersion, we have the following cases

1. 1D: $g(E) \propto \frac{1}{\sqrt{E}}$
2. 2D: $g(E) \propto 1$
3. 3D: $g(E) \propto \sqrt{E}$

Now let us look at the Fermi-Dirac case. Due to the form of $f(E,\mu, T)$, by changing $T$ only states in a range ~$k_B T$ around $E=\mu$ get significantly modified under the integral. When we increase $T$, $f$ broadens about $\mu$ so that it grabs more high-energy states and fewer low-energy states. Now, we should think in each case whether or not this increases or decrease $n$ for each dimension. In 1D, since low-energy states are weighted higher, $n$ will decrease at fixed $\mu$ so we must increase $\mu$ to compensate. Conversely in 3D, low-energy states are weighted lower, so $n$ will increase at fixed $\mu$ so we must decrease $\mu$ to compensate. One should think of increasing/decreasing $\mu$ primarily as changing the zeroth order contribution to compensate for the first-order change (aka the rectangular contribution to adjust for the change in spread of the distribution).

Comment: With the fact that only the states near $E=\mu$ are important to compute the final result you are actually just saying that states with very high energy are not contributing much? If I have understood correctly, in this way you also cut off the set of states with energy between 0 and $\mu - k T$, which contribute a lot to the integral, but this is not very important because it is just a zeroth order approximation to understand how the things should go, right?

Comment: I fixed the answer so that I'm actually saying the right things now. Yes, high energy states don't contribute much because the distribution kills off their contribution. You are correct in noting that low energy states are weighted heavily, but the point is that changing the temperature does not really affect their contribution. All the physics happens at $E=\mu$, so the idea is that we only need to look there, as you correctly note. The deep reason for this is that changes correspond to first derivatives, and $f'(E)$ is roughly a delta function.